# Adding a function call after a builtin runs

Tags: hooks, advice, nadvice

I always want to run `reposition-window` after `c-beginning-of-defun`.

---

I've tried this:

```
(advice-add 'c-beginning-of-defun :after #'reposition-window)
```

it results in this at execution:

```
Variable binding depth exceeds max-specpdl-size
```

---

I've considered hooks, but I don't know how to find a hook for `c-beginning-of-defun`. I don't think hooks are the way to go if it's not for modes.

---

I've tried redefining `c-beginning-of-defun`, but then I need to call to the previous version, and I get infinite recursion.

---

I've tried implementing my own function:

```
(defun my-beginning-of-defun ()
  (interactive)
  (beginning-of-defun)
  (reposition-window))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-a") 'my-beginning-of-defun) ;;; This doesn't bite!
```

but this doesn't work in C, because its major mode overrides `C-M-a` with the C version of the function. I could make my own version of the C function as well, and bind `C-M-a` in my own c-mode-hook, but... It seems like doing work that advises are designed to do.

Answer (score 3):

`reposition-window` calls `beginning-of-defun` to compute the window boundaries.
So you get an infinite recursion when calling `reposition-window` from `c-beginning-of-defun`.

You can add the following guard for avoiding that recursion:

```el
(defvar c-beginning-of-defun-after-hook nil
  "Functions to be run after `c-beginning-of-defun'.")

(advice-add 'c-beginning-of-defun :after (lambda (&rest _args) (run-hooks 'c-beginning-of-defun-after-hook)))

(defun resposition-window-for-c-beginning-of-defun (&rest args)
  "Deactivate `c-beginning-of-defun-after-hook' and call `resposition-window'."
  (let (c-beginning-of-defun-after-hook)
    (reposition-window)))

(add-hook 'c-beginning-of-defun-after-hook #'resposition-window-for-c-beginning-of-defun)
```